# How do you give full access w/ chmod to multiple groups? Need to use ACL's?

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, chmod, launchd

First of all, thanks for reading. I've had success running a plist launchd job that is in my LaunchAgents folder.  It basically calls a small shell script that chmod's a folder's permissions.  I then have another job that calls another script that changes it back to what it was before.

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to chmod a folder/file permissions for a particular group.  I realize that every folder/file has an owner that belongs to a group.  Yes, but how do I explicitly give permissions to another group of users through a shell script?  Is this possible?  I have also been reading about ACL's, is this the route I should go?

My script is simple now:

```
chmod -R 777 <FOLDERNAME>
```

then back:

```
chmod -R 000 <FOLDERNAME>
```

Running this while logged in as the administrator.

But I'd like to grant access for another group, in theory:

`chmod -R 777 <FOLDERNAME> <GROUPNAME>` <-- yup, this is what I'm thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ACLs. First of all, your filesystem must be mounted with that option. You can remount it with that option with:

```
# mount -o remount,acl /mount/point
```

If you want this option static (available after each reboot):

```
# vi /etc/fstab
#...
/dev/partition  /mount/point  fstype  defaults,acl 1 2
```

The important part here, is ",acl" in the options column. Everything else you can ignore.

The you need to install `acl` package, and use `setfacl`. To set defaults for a directory (every new file and subdir created will have those acls):

```
# setfacl -d -m u::rwx,u:user1:rx,g::rx,g:group1:rwx,g:group2:rx,o::- directory
```

- Creation user has full permissions
- user1 has only read an execute
- same for default group
- group1 has read execute and write access
- group2 read and execute
- others have no chance in here

You should now, set permissions on this directory (yes, just strip -d option):

```
# setfacl -m u::rwx,u:user1:rx,g::rx,g:group1:rwx,g:group2:rx,o::- directory
```

NOTICE that if there are any contents in this directory, permissions MUST be explicitly set. You could use find to set up permissions correctly (remember, directories must have read and execute access for people to access/list them). For a start on that subject, find ./ -type d give you subdirectories in current location and the following will setup default permissions for each one of this:

```
# find ./ -type d -exec setfacl -d -m <acl> \{} \;
```

- `<acl>` should be the desired acl
- `\{} \;` is an escape sequence for find.

If you want to check permissions inherited by created files and directories, use `getfacl`

You could also use the -R|--recursive switch, but that would mess up with files and directories permissions.

Comment: Thank you, I'll work on using this solution and get back to you.

Comment: @gabemartinez This answer appears to use Linux. Mac OS X uses extended chmod commands to manipulate ACLs not setfacl. Read the chmod man page for more information.

Comment: missed the tag macosx ... sorry

Comment: I was able to get ACL's to work out just fine.  A great resource was: http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/acl.html  Thank you, all, once again.